# haskell flip simulation problems

Tags: function, haskell, flip

```
flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)   
flip' f = g   
    where g x y = f y x
```

I want to ask that in the above flip' function , it seems that flip' will return a function named g and g x y share the same value with f y x

however, in " where g x y = f y x " , f y x is a function call and will return a value, g x y will aslo return a value, so does it make sense that " where v2 = v1 "?

I know that the code will work but I want to know more about the way it make this happen.

does anybody has an idea? thank you so much

Comment: if " where g x y = f y x " means a function definition of g , then, why would this following code work?                                       flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c   
flip' f y x = f x y  because " f x y " is a value but the return type should be a function

Comment: I don't get why anyone would define it that way rather than `flip' f = \ x y -> f y x` (if you want to be super clear).

Answer (score 4):

In `where g x y = f y x`, `g x y` is not a function call `g` with parameters `x` and `y`. It is a declaration of the function `g` as a function taking 2 arguments `x` and `y` and evaluation to `f y x`.

So it means `flip'` given a function `f` taking 2 arguments will evaluate to `g`. `g` itself being defined as swapping two arguments to call `f`.

Comment: thank you for your help. but how about this code                   flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c                              flip' f y x = f x y because " f x y " is a value but the return type should be a function

Comment: @user3129535 You should *not* think of `=` as an assignment. It's a definition. `flip f y x = f x y` would be like: `def flip(f, y, x): return f(x, y)` in an imperative language. The right hand side of `=` is an expression, while the left hand side is a *declaration* of the function's `flip` parameters.

Comment: @user3129535 Not the same thing. In that case `flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c` take a function `(a -> b -> c)` and a value `b` and a value `a` to return a value `c`. In your question, you were talking of a function taking a function `(a -> b -> c)` and returning a function `(b -> a -> c)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you , I got your idea. but it still confuses me that since f x y is an expression , so it will become a value after evaluation, so the return type is a value, which is in conflict with the signature

Comment: @user3129535 In your question `where g x y = f y x` will only be evaluated when the parameters will be provided to `g`, when we evaluate `g`. So we really return a function taking 2 arguments, a.k.a. `g`.

Comment: @Johan thank you. you are right . But how can Haskell tell the usage of = in where. I mean " where a = 10 " is an assignment or a local function definition named a , takes no param, return 10?

Comment: @user3129535 There is no such thing as an assignement, so yes you can see it as a function that can be evaluated without arguments, a.k.a. a constant, an alias, etc...

Comment: The expression on the left side of = is never evaluated. If it is one variable, the equation defines a value. If it is n variables, the equation defines a function of n-1 parameters.   `f x y = ...` means the same as `f = \ x y -> ...`